# React KeyboardEvent change input value after onPressEnter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

I have an input that I need to reset the value with the method called by `onPressEnter` This is the input:

```
<Input
    type="text"
    placeholder="new account"
    onPressEnter={(event) => this.onCreateAccount(event)}>
</Input>
```

and this is the method called:

```
onCreatePitch(event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>, accountId: number) {
    this.props.onCreatePitch(event.currentTarget.value, accountId);
    /* event.currentTarget.value = '';  can't do this, it's a read only value*/
}
```

as you can see `event.currentTarget.value` will not work as it's a read only value & `event.target.value` is not a valid type. Not sure what to do here thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you need to make this a [Controlled Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

Comment: React uses `state`, your value property of you input should then use this,.. So when you want to reset, you would do something like `setState({input: ""})` etc.  You rarely need to access DOM directly,..

Comment: Are you using antd form to maintain state?

Comment: @Max no I was trying to not to have to go that route, but I'm guessing I have to.

Comment: If you aren't, then Shawn's answer should work.

Comment: This works fine for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/w2w1yvx758 (I didn't replicate your code exactly cause it seems to be off; there's no `onCreateAccount` function)

Comment: thank @ChrisG this leads me to believe that somthing else is happening in my component to cause it to not work. possibly componentWillRecieveProps, as when this method is fired, the component recieves new props.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say "can't do this", what exactly do you mean? Are you getting an error message?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a state that controls the value of the input

```
state = {
  value: ""
}

onEnterPress(event) {
 if (event is Enter) {
   this.setState({value: ""})
   return
 }
}

<Input
    type="text"
    placeholder="new account"
    value={this.state.value}
    onPressEnter={this.onEnterPressed} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Component

```
<Input
    type="text"
    placeholder="new account"
    onKeyDown={onCreateAccount}>
</Input>
```

Function

```
 const onCreateAccount = (event) => {
       if(event.key === 'Enter') {
       
       }
    }
```